# What is the difference between a function and a lambda?

Tags: functional-programming, methods, lambda

I'm a little bit confused about 'function' and 'lambda'.  I've seen some examples showing that the scheme keyword `lambda` works very similarly to the JavaScript keyword `function`, but I really don't know how they are related.

I'm told that 'function' and 'method' can be used interchangeably when speaking about objects in .net.  I'm wondering if 'lambda' and 'function' similarly mean the same thing.  I wonder if 'lambda' has some esoteric meaning, seeing that the Greek letter lambda (λ) appears in so many avatars on this site.  To make things even more confusing, in .net, the functional parts of C# refer to function expressions passed to another function as 'lambda expressions', so the word really seems to be all over the place.

I'm also vaguely familiar with the term 'lambda calculus'.

What is the difference between a function and a lambda?

Comment: Nitpick - they are called "lambda expressions", not "lambda functions", at least as far as C#/.NET documentation goes.

Comment: @TWith2Sugars - Read the message. Your answer is low quality as it pretty much is just a link, so got converted to a comment.

Comment: `I wonder if 'lambda' has some esoteric meaning, seeing that the Greek letter lambda (λ) appears in so many avatars on this site.` One would hope it would be in reference to lambda calculus, but I have a strange feeling [Half Life](http://images.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/Half-Life-half-life-663708_1024_768.jpg) is to blame for lambda avatars.

Comment: Fair enough, here is the link to the stackoverflow answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox: I suspect you're correct about the Half-Life influence. :/

Answer (score 48):

The word "lambda" or "lambda expressions" most often refers to anonymous functions. So in that sense a lambda is a kind of function, but not every function is a lambda (i.e. named functions aren't usually referred to as lambdas). Depending on the language, anonymous functions are often implemented differently than named functions (particularly in languages where anonymous functions are closures and named functions are not), so referring to them with different terms can make sense.

The difference between scheme's lambda keyword and Javascript's function keyword is that the latter can be used to create both anonymous functions and named functions while the former only creates anonymous functions (and you'd use `define` to create named functions).

The lambda calculus is a minimal programming language/mathematical model of computation, which uses functions as its only "data structure". In the lamdba calculus the lambda-symbol is used to create (anonymous) functions. This is where the usage of the term "lambda" in other languages comes from.

Comment: That is extremely rough.  You use `define` (or `let` or one of its relatives, or an internal define) to create names -- that's all.  There's nothing special in `define` with respect to functions.

Comment: @EliBarzilay Well, `define` *does* have a special form for defining functions (i.e. you can write `(define (f x) (foo))` instead of `(define f (lambda (x) (foo)))`), but my point was that you can't create a named function using `lambda` alone, i.e. you can't write something like `(lambda f (x) (foo))` to define a function named `f` that takes one argument like you can with Javascript's `function` keyword.

Comment: `define` has that as a syntactic sugar, so it's not as important as its role as a name binding tool for all values.  As for `lambda` not creating a name by itself: that's an important feature, since it separates name giving from function forms...  IMO JS is doing the right thing in allowing the separation while also accepting an optional name for those masses who would be horrified at the idea of a function with no name.  (And luckily the size of those masses are in a general decline...)

Answer (score 21):

A lambda is simply an anonymous function - a function with no name.

Comment: Note Quite: lambda's can contain state (as in closure does) that they snag from the context where they are declared.

Comment: So could a named function, if the language lets you declare nested functions.

Comment: Kudos for making it into the "low quality posts" review tab with an upvoted answer.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox - Not intentionally, I can assure you.

Comment: Not really, a `lambda` expression in Scheme is just like a `function` expression with no name -- *but* there's nothing stopping you from later giving them a name.  For example `var f = [function(x){return x;}][0]`.  You could argue that the function value itself has no name, but that would be true for all functions...

Comment: Do lambdas actually belong to functional programming?

Comment: I think that definition might need some work. A lambda is simply **a function that is used as data** (i.e., a function that is used as an argument in a higher-order function). Not all lambdas are anonymous as they need to be named in order to invoke recursion, for example.

Answer (score 10):

Answered Here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function

Basically Lambda is an anonymous function.

Comment: So instead of...?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove that part before posting :|

Comment: Please don't use "basically".  It suggests you're dumbing it down.

Answer (score 8):

In C# *Anonymous function* is a general term that includes both lambda expressions and anonymous methods (anonymous methods are delegate instances with no actual method declaration).

*Lambda expressions* can be broken down to *expression lambda* and *statement lambda*

Expression lambda:

```
(int x, string y) => x == y.Length
```

Statement lambda is similar to expression lambda except the statement(s) are enclosed in braces:

```
(int x, string y) => {
         if (x == y.Length) {
             Console.WriteLine(y);
         }
}
```

When we talk about lambda expressions in JavaScript that basically just means using a function as an argument in a call to another function.

```
var calculate = function(x, y, operation){
    return operation(x, y);
}

// we're passing anonymous function as a third argument
calculate(10, 15, function(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}); // 25
```

Comment: +1 A lot of people have mentioned that lambdas are anonymous functions, but there is more to it than that. The body (right hand side) of a lambda is often an **expression** rather than a statement block. The body of a named function being an expression is typically allowed (or required) in functional languages, but not imperative languages.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR As others pointed out: the lambda notation is just a way to define functions without being forced to give them a name.

**Long version**

I would like to elaborate a bit on this topic because I find it very interesting. Disclaimer: I have taken my course on lambda calculus a long time ago. If someone with better knowledge finds any inaccuracies in my answer, feel free to help me improve it.

Let's start with expressions, e.g. `1 + 2` and `x + 2`. Literals such as `1` and `2` are called **constants** because they are bound to specific fixed values.

An identifier such as `x` is called **variable** and in order to evaluate it you need to bind it to some value first. So, basically you cannot evaluate `x + 1` as long as you do not know what `x` is.

The lambda notation provides a schema for binding specific input values to variables. A **lambda expression** can be formed by adding `λx .` in front of an existing expression, e.g. `λx . x + 1`. Variable `x` is said to be **free** in `x + 1` and **bound** in `λx . x + 1`

How does this help in evaluating expressions? If you feed a value to the lambda expression, like so

```
(λx . x + 1) 2
```

then you can evaluate the whole expression by replacing (binding) all occurrences of the variable `x` with the value 2:

```
(λx . x + 1) 2
      2 + 1
      3
```

So, the lambda notation provides a general mechanism for binding things to variables that appear in an expression / program block. Depending on the context, this creates sightly different concepts in programming languages:

- In a purely functional language like Haskell, lambda expressions represent **functions** in the mathematical sense: an input value is injected into the body of the lambda and an output value is produced.
- In many languages (e.g. JavaScript, Python, Scheme) evaluating the body of a lambda expression can have side-effects. In this case one can use the term **procedure** to mark the difference wrt pure functions.

Apart from the differences, the lambda notation is about defining formal parameters and binding them to actual parameters.

The next step, is to give a function / procedure a name.
In several languages, functions are values like any other, so you can give a function a name as follows:

```
(define f (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))      ;; Scheme

f = \x -> x + 1                      -- Haskell

val f: (Int => Int) = x => x + 1     // Scala

var f = function(x) { return x + 1 } // JavaScript

f = lambda x: x + 1                  # Python
```

As Eli Barzilay pointed out, these definition just bind the name `f` to a value, which happens to be a function. So in this respect, functions, numbers, strings, characters are all values that can be bound to names in the same way:

```
(define n 42)   ;; Scheme

n = 42          -- Haskell

val n: Int = 42 // Scala

var n = 42      // JavaScript

n = 42          # Python
```

In these languages you can also bind a function to a name using the more familiar (but equivalent) notation:

```
(define (f x) (+ x 1))         ;; Scheme

f x = x + 1                    -- Haskell

def f(x: Int): Int = x + 1     // Scala

function f(x) { return x + 1 } // JavaScript

def f(x): return x + 1         # Python
```

Some languages, e.g. C, only support the latter notation for defining (named) functions.

**Closures**

Some final observations regarding **closures**. Consider the expression `x + y`. This contains two free variables. If you bind `x` using the lambda notation you get:

```
\x -> x + y
```

This is not (yet) a function because it still contains a free variable `y`. You could make a function out of it by binding `y` as well:

```
\x -> \y -> x + y
```

or

```
\x y -> x + y
```

which is just the same as the `+` function.

But you can bind, say, `y` in another way (*):

```
incrementBy y = \x -> x + y
```

The result of applying function incrementBy to a number is a closure, i.e. a function / procedure whose body contains a free variable (e.g. `y`) that has been bound to a value from the environment in which the closure was defined.

So `incrementBy 5` is the function (closure) that increments numbers by 5.

**NOTE (*)**

I am cheating a bit here:

```
incrementBy y = \x -> x + y
```

is equivalent to

```
incrementBy = \y -> \x -> x + y
```

so the binding mechanism is the same. Intuitively, I think of a closure as representing a chunk of a more complex lambda expression. When this representation is created, some of the bindings of the mother expression have already been set and the closure uses them later when it gets evaluated / invoked.

Comment: Im just a begginer, but I think this can be a bit confusing if you are trying to understand λ calculus in the mathematical sense, since what you call constants are called variables and denoted by the symbols a,b,c... What you call variables would be an undetermined variable 
**x**. On the other hand 1 is λ**f** **x**. **f** **x**, 2 is  λ**f** **x**. **f** (**f** **x**) and so on.

Comment: @jinawee: I admit I did not look up the exact definition. I remember using the terms variables and constants in logic. There, a constant is a symbol that is mapped to a domain, whereas a variable is a symbol you can quantify over. But, again, (1) it is a long time ago since I took a course on logic, and (2) lambda-calculus need not follow 1-1 the concepts of mathematical logic. If you point me to a reference I can try and fix my terminology.

Answer (score 0):

"Lambda" in programming usually means "lambda function" (or also "lambda expression", "lambda term"). When function is a named block of code defined before its usage, "lambda function" is a block of code (or an expression) defined in place of the usage that can be used as a first-class citizen in a programming language.

In JavaScript ES6 (2015) there's a short syntax to define lambdas called ["Arrow Functions"](http://es6-features.org/#ExpressionBodies). In C# such syntax [was introduced in .NET 3.0 (around 2006)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/09/16/c-3-0-lambda-expressions-i-dont-like-it-that-much/).

In math a "function" notion has several meanings where one of the meanings is about a function's notation (i.e. how to write it down), then "lambda function" (in calculus) is a special kind of function notation. For more discussion check [lambda functions in programming languages](http://dobegin.com/lambda-functions-everywhere/).